# ExtJs - checkbox selection in form

Tags: javascript, extjs

[image]

I want to check all checkboxes in a form when user click on top checkbox. If any checkbox uncheck i want to uncheck top checkbox. I need same functionality like grid checkbox column.

ExtJS version: 6.2.1

Comment: Have you looked at the extjs checkbox documentation, it seems they have implemented a check all/deselect all that could maybe point you in the right direction, If you want more help i would suggest you post your code and talk through what you have already tried. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.form.field.Checkbox.html

Comment: @JessPatton, I will check and let you know

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`xtype: checkboxgroup`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.form.CheckboxGroup.html).

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2eqp)**, I have create a demo using `checkboxgroup`. I hope this will help you to achieve your requirement.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Example',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {

            bodyPadding: 10,

            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

            items: [{
                xtype: 'checkboxgroup',
                layout: 'vbox',
                fieldLabel: 'Privilege',
                checkedArr: [],
                defaults: {
                    flex: 1,
                    name: 'mycheck',

                    listeners: {
                        change: function (field, newValue, oldValue) {
                            var group = field.up('checkboxgroup');

                            if (field.name == 'all') {
                                group.doCheckUnCheckAll(newValue);
                            } else {
                                var len = group.query('[name=mycheck]').length,
                                    allCB = group.down('[name=all]');

                                if (newValue) {
                                    group.checkedArr.push(field.inputValue)
                                } else {
                                    Ext.Array.remove(group.checkedArr, field.inputValue);
                                }
                                group.doSetCBValue(allCB, len == group.checkedArr.length);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                /**
                 * this function will set value of checkbox and do event suspend & resume
                 * @param {Checbox}
                 * @param {Boolean}
                 */
                doSetCBValue: function (f, v) {
                    //Check or uncheck
                    f.suspendEvent('change');
                    f.setValue(v);
                    f.resumeEvent('change');
                },

                /**
                 * This event will check or uncheck the all checkbox when {ALL} checkbox has beed checked/unchecked
                 * @param {Boolean}
                 */
                doCheckUnCheckAll: function (isCheck) {
                    this.query('[name=mycheck]').forEach(f => {
                        this.doSetCBValue(f, isCheck);
                        //For checking to other checkbox is checked or not
                        if (isCheck) {
                            if (this.checkedArr.indexOf(f.inputValue) == -1)
                                this.checkedArr.push(f.inputValue);
                        } else {
                            Ext.Array.remove(this.checkedArr, f.inputValue);
                        }
                    });
                },

                items: [{
                    boxLabel: 'ALL',
                    inputValue: 'all',
                    name: 'all'
                }, {
                    boxLabel: 'Item 1',
                    inputValue: '1'
                }, {
                    boxLabel: 'Item 2',
                    inputValue: '2'
                }, {
                    boxLabel: 'Item 3',
                    inputValue: '3'
                }, {
                    boxLabel: 'Item 4',
                    inputValue: '4'
                }, {
                    boxLabel: 'Item 5',
                    inputValue: '5'
                }, {
                    boxLabel: 'Item 6',
                    inputValue: '6'
                }]
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Jadav, It works. May i know is it possible with out checkboxgroup? All my forms are using only checkbox. So i should migrate all of them?

Comment: It can also done by `checboxfield` you just need to put same logic.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll have to implement the custom logic yourself.

I would suggest using the `Ext.form.CheckboxGroup` component and listen to the change event ([see example in docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.CheckboxGroup.html#event-change)). The value of the group would look something like this:

```
{    
 "Privileges": [
   "All",
   "Visible",
   "Manage"    
 ] 
}
```

Depending on the value of the group dynamically check or uncheck each checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

As **ground_call** said, you need to implement custom logic. One of approaches is to set checkbox group, and assign `itemId` to top checkbox. In `ViewController` create listener on `change` event for that top checkbox, that will turn on/off all other checkboxes. Other checkboxes you can handle via `checkboxgroup`'s `change` event. Here is fiddle with template for this implementation: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2eqm

Comment: @Grigority Mikhaliki, Thanks i checked your fiddle. Problem with your example is if i uncheck item2 it is not un checking root check box. So i need like if i check root checkbox all checkbox items need to check. if i uncheck any sub checkbox it needs to uncheck root checkbox.